# Set an attribute inside the model of a one-to-many relationship in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to set a relationship attribute inside the parent model (Articles) and return the most recent object of the RelevantFlag. The Articles and RelevantFlag models are a one-to-many relationship thus my models look like this:

```
class Article(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    relevant_flag = db.relationship(
        'RelevantFlag',
        backref="Article",
        lazy='dynamic'
        )

    # Get the latest RelevantFlag model object
    def getLatestRelevance(self):
        return Article.query.join(
            RelevantFlag
            ).filter(
                RelevantFlag.id == self.id
            ).order_by(
                Article.id.desc()
            ).first()

    def setRelevance(self, state):
        # Set the boolean to what's passed in 'state'

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Article {}>'.format(self.id)

class RelevantFlag(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    article_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('article.id'))
    state = db.Column(db.Boolean)
```

My question is, how do I write a setter to change the RelevantFlag's state attribute inside the Articles model?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want to change a column value by accessing a one-to-many relationship?

```
def setRelevance(self, state):
    # Set the boolean to what's passed in 'state'
    self.relevant_flag.state = state
```